# An API that reads mails that are unread with certain description, but when read remove the label UNREAD

Tags: python, api, gmail-api

I have a Python script that interacts with the Gmail API and searches mails that are unread, with certain description and from specific email addresses. But I want it so when it reads the mail it removes the UNREAD label so it doesn't detect it when I run the script again.

> 

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """

    email_address1 = "mensajeria@bancoestado.cl"
    email_address2 = "noreply@correo.bancoestado.cl"

    creds = None
    
    
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Gmail API
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])

    #Get Messages
    results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=['INBOX'], q=f'from:{email_address1} OR from:{email_address2} is:unread').execute()
    messages = results.get('messages', [])

    #Messages Filter
    message_count = 100
    for message in messages[:message_count]:
        msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
        email = (msg['snippet'])
        if "que recibiste Monto $" in email:
            print(f'{email}\n')
            service.users().messages().modify(userId='me', id=message['id'], body={'removeLabelIds': ['UNREAD']}).execute()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The script works just fine until it reaches my attempt of removing the UNREAD label so it doesn't detect it again. Here

```
service.users().messages().modify(userId='me', id=message['id'], body={'removeLabelIds': ['UNREAD']}).execute()
```

I know it can be done, because in the labels section of the Gmail API documentation it says that the UNREAD label can be manually changed.

So if someone could give me a hand I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I've already found a solution. The problem was that the scope that I was using didn't had the permissions needed to remove a label from a message, so I changed the scope to this instead and it worked just fine.

```
SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']
```